# Vue project not working with https on apache server. SSL certificates are installed

Tags: apache, vue.js, http, https

I have a vue project **http://4munjz.com** which is working fine with **http** as follow
[image]

But when we use **https** it does not work and load the files and directories
[image]

We are using apache server and ssl certificates are also installed. I have no idea what is the problem and where it is. I shall be thankfull if anybody can help to fix this issue

Comment: This is a problem with the apache configuration. Can you post the configuration?

Comment: which configuration file? Can you please share the file name which I have to share?